# Can't use "print" command with octave

Tags: plot, octave

Im trying to save a plot to a file, when using the print command i get this error:

```
print "data"
```

> Unknown device: pswrite
>
> Unrecoverable error: undefined in .uninstallpagedevice
>
> Operand stack:
>       defaultdevice
>   warning: broken pipe`

Answer (score 0):

You should realy provide more infos when asking for help with software. What OS are you running? Which Octave version? Installed from repo or source? What graphics_toolkit?

But I've asked my crystal ball and I guess it's a problem with ghostscript. Ghostscript versions >= 9.09 removed the pswrite command, see also https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?41141

So install a older version of ghostscript or a newer version of GNU Octave or use the qt or fltk graphics_toolkit.